# Push Notifications in React-Native Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm using RN Firebase for push notifications. Application is receiving notifications but sound and vibration not working for IOS and Android.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Share the body of notification

Comment: Adding Codes Examples, and error output logs will help answer your question

Comment: @OliverD This is what I got from a backend guy.
Fcmex.push(users_list,
      notification: %{
        title: data.title,
        body: data.description
      },
      data: data
    )

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

All you need to do is configure Notification Payload